# JAXB marshalls only root when marshalling to node

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal a new header to SOAP message, but JAXB only marshalls the root of the Java object. When I try to marshal it to System output the marshalling goes OK.

*Note: namespaces are replaced with XXX/YYY/... due to stackoverflow spam checks*

Marhsalling code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;

// <..>

private void marshal(RequestDestinationMetaDTO requestDestinationMetaDTO, SOAPHeader soapHeader) throws JAXBException {
    final UserContextDTO userContextDTO = new UserContextDTO(...);
    final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserContextDTO.class).createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(userContextDTO, System.out);
    marshaller.marshal(userContextDTO, soapHeader);
}
```

Object to marhsal:

```
package ru.solit.esb.apigate.header.manager.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import ru.mos.emias.usercontext.UserContext;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@XmlRootElement(namespace = UserContextDTO.NAMESPACE_URI, name = "userContext")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class UserContextDTO extends UserContext {

    public static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "YYY";

    /**
     * Default constructor for xml marshalling
     * @noinspection unused
     */
    public UserContextDTO() {
        super(null, null, 0L, null, null, 0L, null, null);
    }

    public UserContextDTO(UserContext userContext) {
        super(
                userContext.getSystemName(),
                userContext.getUserName(),
                userContext.getUserRoleId(),
                userContext.isUserRoleSystemWide(),
                userContext.getUserRights(),
                userContext.getJobExecutionId(),
                userContext.getHostIp(),
                userContext.getHostName()
        );
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public String getSystemName() {
        return super.getSystemName();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return super.getUserName();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public long getUserRoleId() {
        return super.getUserRoleId();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public Boolean isUserRoleSystemWide() {
        return super.isUserRoleSystemWide();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, name = "userRights")
    public List<UserRightDTO> getUserRightDTOs() {
        final List<Long> userRights = super.getUserRights();
        if (userRights == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return userRights.stream().map(UserRightDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public long getJobExecutionId() {
        return super.getJobExecutionId();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public String getHostIp() {
        return super.getHostIp();
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Override
    public String getHostName() {
        return super.getHostName();
    }

    @XmlType(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class UserRightDTO {

        @XmlElement(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
        private Long userRightId;

    }

}
```

Source message:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="XXX">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

System.out result:

```xml
<userContext xmlns="YYY">
    <jobExecutionId>0</jobExecutionId>
    <systemName>24cb7aeea4b1f5fcca336243f3b89ebb5131</systemName>
    <userName>0</userName>
    <userRights>
        <userRightId>6206941629831905910</userRightId>
    </userRights>
    <userRoleId>-8952814757693617916</userRoleId>
    <userRoleSystemWide>true</userRoleSystemWide>
</userContext>
```

Marshalling to header node result:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
  <soap:Header><ns5:userContext xmlns:ns5="YYY"/></soap:Header><soap:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="XXX">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Expecting result:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
  <soap:Header>
<userContext xmlns="YYY">
    <jobExecutionId>0</jobExecutionId>
    <systemName>24cb7aeea4b1f5fcca336243f3b89ebb5131</systemName>
    <userName>0</userName>
    <userRights>
        <userRightId>6206941629831905910</userRightId>
    </userRights>
    <userRoleId>-8952814757693617916</userRoleId>
    <userRoleSystemWide>true</userRoleSystemWide>
</userContext>
</soap:Header><soap:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="XXX">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

**I tried** removing @XmlRootElement(namespace = UserContextDTO.NAMESPACE_URI, name = "userContext") and marshalling the object as JAXBElement, because I thought it might do the trick:

```
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<>(new QName("YYY", "userContext", "ctx"), UserContextDTO.class, userContextDTO), soapHeader);
marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<>(new QName("YYY", "userContext", "ctx"), UserContextDTO.class, userContextDTO), System.out);
```

But it just didn't

---

**I tried** marshalling this node into another element - it worked. But if I try to move the node - it just clears its' contents again:

```
private void marshal(RequestDestinationMetaDTO requestDestinationMetaDTO, SOAPHeader soapHeader) throws JAXBException, SOAPException {
        final UserContextDTO userContextDTO = new UserContextDTO(new UserContextBuilder(
                requestDestinationMetaDTO.getExternalSystemToken(),
                "0",
                Collections.singletonList(requestDestinationMetaDTO.getPublicationMethodRight()))
                .withUserRoleId(requestDestinationMetaDTO.getExternalSystemUserRoleId())
                .withUserRoleSystemWide(true)
                .withJobExecutionId(0)
                .build());

        final Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserContextDTO.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        final QName userContextQName = headerManagerQNamesConfiguration.getUserContextQName();
        soapHeader.addNamespaceDeclaration(userContextQName.getPrefix(), userContextQName.getNamespaceURI());
        final SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(userContextQName);
        marshaller.marshal(userContextDTO, soapHeaderElement);
        final SOAPElement soapElement = (SOAPElement) soapHeaderElement.getFirstChild();
        soapHeader.addChildElement(soapElement);

        marshaller.marshal(userContextDTO, System.out);
    }
```

Result:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xmlns:xsd="...">
  <soap:Header xmlns:ctx="YYY">
    <ctx:userContext>
      <ctx:userContext>
        <ctx:jobExecutionId>0</ctx:jobExecutionId>
        <ctx:systemName>13b78475c82356f4e9</ctx:systemName> 
        <ctx:userName>0</ctx:userName>
        <ctx:userRights> 
          <ctx:userRightId>-8110359214033630382</ctx:userRightId> 
        </ctx:userRights> 
        <ctx:userRoleId>7497095867686755286</ctx:userRoleId>
        <ctx:userRoleSystemWide>true</ctx:userRoleSystemWide>
      </ctx:userContext>
    </ctx:userContext>
    <ctx:userContext/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="XXX">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

**My temp workaround** is to manually build the node:

```
final QName userContextQName = headerManagerQNamesConfiguration.getUserContextQName();
soapHeader.addNamespaceDeclaration(userContextQName.getPrefix(), userContextQName.getNamespaceURI());
final SOAPHeaderElement soapHeaderElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(userContextQName);
soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("systemName").setTextContent(userContextDTO.getSystemName());
soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("userName").setTextContent(userContextDTO.getUserName());
soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("userRoleId").setTextContent(String.valueOf(userContextDTO.getUserRoleId()));
soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("isUserRoleSystemWide").setTextContent(String.valueOf(userContextDTO.isUserRoleSystemWide()));
final SOAPElement soapElement = soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("userRights");
for (Long userRight : userContextDTO.getUserRights()) {
    soapElement.addChildElement("userRightId").setTextContent(String.valueOf(userRight));
}
soapHeaderElement.addChildElement("jobExecutionId").setTextContent(String.valueOf(userContextDTO.getJobExecutionId()));
```